# Has this double-slit experiment been performed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

A weak, single photon, source is controlled by a fast shutter and directs photons toward a double-slit. Quite far beyond the slits, compared to shutter speed, is the photon detector (perhaps a film). Timed to the shutter action one of the slits is closed after the photon is calculated to be between the slits and detectors.

Does the double-slit or single-slit pattern accumulate?

Comment: Of course. I don't remember by whom, but you can find in Wikipedia.

Comment: The Wiki articles describe other double-slit experiments: I am interested in this form of the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is called *Delayed-choice Double-slit Experiment* first thought by physicist John Wheeler.

Its result is that our present observations/ actions affect the past. When you observe/ close one slit after photon (or, any other Quantum denizen) has passed it (based on calculation), the two-slit interference pattern doesn’t form. It acts like it passed only from one slit.

Comment: Which interference pattern doesn't form, the single slit or double slit?

Comment: @Joshua Interference pattern can only form if photon passes through more than one slit. What are you asking?

Comment: Single-slit diffraction, which really exists.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction#Single-slit_diffraction

Comment: @Joshua In that case, result would be single-slit one as if the other slit wasn't in existence. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wave interference patterns are created with more than one opening for the particle to pass through. With only one slit, the wave passing through it would not meet another wave beyond the screen to interfere with it. Imagine it like the waves produced by dropping a pebble into a calm body of water. When the uniform ripples get to the screen with two slits in it the ripples (waves) are divided beyond the screen and are then two distinct waves that spread out and merge, causing the familiar interference as they blend together. The result is the particle riding a wave to an not assured place on the aforementioned film, with the center of the film being the *most likely* area that the particle will land. To get a good visual and a more detailed explanation visit Wikipedia's [Double Slit Experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment).

Comment: My question is: has this experiment been performed, not what does one think would happen if it were performed.